# Port scanning germany

Tags: security, port, scanning, port-scanning

In uni, we are right now doing network security. I live in germany. Can anyone tell me if there are any networks, that i may scan for testing/learning purposes?

Are there such networks/URLs ? I do not want to offend anyone or get into any legal trouble. I am looking for a perfectly legal way, other than scanning my own machine.

Best regards

Comment: That your university is "teaching" you to use tools without providing a suitable environment in which to conduct experiments / apply your knowledge seems very innappropriate to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not suggest you to scan any server from the internet. For learning purposes, its truly recommended that you create your own VMs and your own private network to play. Search on internet witch OS are most used for server and used them in stock or updated version and have fun ;).

Is there some hack me websites available, but again, read a lot their licenses and agreements and terms. Justo Google It "Hack me".